# Posts made to category don't show up (do show up on frontpage)

Tags: categories, loop

Added a subcategory to WordPress. Wrote a blog post and attached it to this subcategory. Now for some reason when I check it on my site, it give me the below error:

```
Sorry, you are looking for something that isn't here.
```

The weird thing is that I can still access the post from the front page, and it shows me the correct URL:

```
subdomain.domain.com/category/subcategory/postname
```

But when i remove "postname", it says it can't find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: As it was showing on the frontpage, I tried adding the frontpage code to a custom category page, but this didn't work either... .

Comment: can you accesss the new subcategory from the category menu or from a category widget? what is the permalink that shows in these cases? i assume it should be: `subdomain.domain.com/category/maincategory/subcategory`

Answer (score 1):

so your permalinks are `/%category%/%postname%`, are you using a plugin to remove the category base? typically path to the category page would be

```
subdomain.domain.com/category/*categoryname*/*subcategoryname*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Milo. Meanwhile, I found a solution. I did indeed remove the category base from the permalinks and adding .html to it fixed the problem. I've also quickly described it in more detail here: http://tech.wouterbertels.be/wordpress/category-page-shows-no-posts/.